# How can I handle with "IRdisplay can only be used from the IPython R kernel and R magic"?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am new on R. I am using RStudio (Version 1.2.5033), also I work on Microsoft Windows. Working in a project, I realized the following error in my code.

```
library(tidyverse)

options(repr.plot.width = 12, repr.plot.height = 6)

theme_custom <- function(base_size, ...){
  ggplot2::theme_gray(base_size = base_size, ...) +
    ggplot2::theme(
      plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold'),
      plot.subtitle = element_text(color = '#333333'),
      panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#EBF4F7"),
      strip.background = element_rect(fill = "#33AACC"),
      legend.position = "bottom"
    )
}
ggplot2::theme_set(theme_custom(base_size = 20))
ggplot2::update_geom_defaults("line", list(size = 1.5))

# Utility functions

display_df <- function(x){
  d <- as.character(
    knitr::kable(x, format = 'html', table.attr = "class='dataframe'")
  )
  IRdisplay::display_html(d)
}

display_head <- function(x, n = 6){
  display_df(head(x, n))
}

display_random <- function(x, n = 6){
  display_df(dplyr::sample_n(x, n))
}

# Number of new cases observed in a day
k = 0:69

# Arrival rate of new infections per day
lambda = c(10, 20, 30, 40)

poisson_densities = crossing(lambda = lambda, k = k) %>%
  mutate(p = dpois(k, lambda))

display_head(poisson_densities)
```

The outcome of error  is:

*display_head(poisson_densities)
Warning message:
In getOption("jupyter.base_display_func")(data, metadata) :
IRdisplay can only be used from the IPython R kernel and R magic.*

**How can I fix it?**

Comment: According to its description, the package IRdisplay is meant to be used in a Jupyter notebook (a particular kind of online notebook that executes the code and display the results in the same document). So it won't work in RStudio. Instead, you can use the function `head()` to display the beginning of a dataframe. Or here, you can simply type the name of `poisson_densities` and it will display nicely.

Comment: @Alexlok Thank you! It worked well.